# Error is finding second largest number from given string in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find a second largest number from a given string but it's not giving me exact result which I want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SecondLargest {
    public static void secondlarge(char[] arr,int arr_size) {
        int i,first,second;
        first = second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(i = 0 ; i < arr_size ; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > first) {
                second =first;
                first= arr[i];
            }
            else if (arr[i] > second && arr[i] != first)
                second = arr[i];
        }
        if (second == Integer.MIN_VALUE)    
            System.out.println("There is no second largest element\n"); 
        else
            System.out.println("The second largest element is "+second); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  { 

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the String ");
        String userString = scan.nextLine();
        char[] stringToCharArray = userString.toCharArray();

        int n = stringToCharArray.length;
        secondlarge(stringToCharArray, n);
    }           
}
```

The output is looking like this

> Enter the String 52236 The second largest element is 53

The largest number should be only 5 bit'sits showing me 53 in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is correct (in a way): 53 is the ASCII code for `'5'`.

You go over your String as a `char[] arr`, and each `char` in there is (once you put it into an `int`) the Unicode code point of the character.

You could adjust the way it is printed:

```
 System.out.println("The second largest element is "+ (char) second);
```

or avoid putting it into an `int` type variable in the first place (if you keep as a `char` it will print as intended).

---

Also note that your approach is a bit fragile, it will do unexpected things when the input String contains non-digit characters such as letters.